# Dynamically changing the selected value of dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I have an odd behavior that I want to implement on my dropdown. I have two scenarios and both will have different default selected values.

Scenario 1: If user role is admin, then dropdown will not be disabled and 'Select Location' placeholder will show up as selected default.

Scenario 2: if user role is clerk, then dropdown will be disabled and the selected value will be a specific location from the dropdown selection.

While I got the role permission and disabled/enabled thing setup, I'm not sure how to dynamically change the selected value of the dropdown. This is inside reactive forms form group, so not sure I can use ngModel or can I?

Here's my dropdown:

```
 <select [ngModel]="null" formControlName="location" required >
    <option value="null" disabled>{{'SelectLocation' | translate}}</option>
    <option selected *ngFor="let store of location" [ngValue]="store._storeKey">{{ store._storeName }}</option>
</select>
```

Here's the check I have that disables/enables the dropdown:

```
checkUserPermissions() {
    if (this.userPermissions._userPrivilegeKey === 100) {
      //TODO: Default to store2 of list for example
      this.transactionForm.controls['location'].value = stores._store; // This is right? 
      this.transactionForm.controls['location'].disable();
    } else if (this.userPermissions._userPrivilegeKey === 200) {
      //TODO: Default to select location placeholder (currently working)
      this.transactionForm.controls['location'].enable();
    } 
  }
```

Comment: don't you think your function must have to be 1 parameter to select `this` example:
`qcheckUserPermission(a){ 
if(a.userPermissions._userPrivilageKey ===100)
}` example like this?

Comment: do you really need a function just to enable and disable. You can simply use `[disabled]='someCondition'` and `[(ngModel)]="varInClass"` this is the minimum you require. Why make things complex?

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar I'm calling the checkUserPermissions function instead the subscribe of my service call which gets the userPermissions, so I don't need to pass it in.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you do not have an NgModel? You could simply set the value in the method when you enable/disabled the control and be done with it?

Comment: @Delta This is inside a reactive forms group. Can I still use NgModel?

Comment: @Euridice01 I am not familiar with Reactive forms group so I am not sure, it is a normal piece of Angular so I would guess you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the patchValue function instead of directly assigning the value when dealing with forms

```
this.transactionForm.controls['location'].patchValue(stores._store)
```